# Approximate $\arctan\frac89$ using $\arctan 1$ with Taylor of first order. How many digits can I guarantee?

Tags: calculus, approximation

Approximate $\arctan\frac89$ using $\arctan 1$ with Taylor of first order. How many digits can I guarantee?

My apporximation is $\frac\pi4-\frac1{18}\sim0.7298$.

$f''(x)=\frac{-2x}{(x^2+1)^2}$

We know that: $f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac12f''(z)(x-a),$ z between $a$ and $x$

Let's say the error is $\epsilon\left(\frac89\right)=-\frac{1}{81}\frac{z}{(z^2+1)^2}$

As $\frac89<z<1 \rightarrow 0<\frac{z}{(z^2+1)^2}<1 \rightarrow-\frac1{81}<\epsilon\left(\frac89\right)<0$.

We have that

$$\frac\pi4-\frac1{18}>\arctan\left(\frac89\right)>\frac\pi4-\frac1{18}-\frac1{81}$$
$$0.7298>\arctan\left(\frac89\right)>0.7174$$

More precisely (with a calculator) I know that $\arctan\left(\frac89\right)\sim0.726642$

I can guarantee just 1 digit. But I see that I really can guarantee 2, did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do better using
$$\tan ^{-1}(a)-\tan ^{-1}(b)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a-b}{1+a b}\right)$$ So
$$\tan ^{-1}(1)-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{17}\right)\implies \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)=\frac \pi 4-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{17}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{17}-\frac{1}{3(17)^3} <\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{17}\right) <\frac{1}{17}$$ So, converting to decimal,
$$0.7265746<\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)<0.7266425$$ while the exact value is $0.7266423$.

Comment: Can I know where did you get that interval for $\tan^-1\left(\frac1{17}\right)$

Comment: @Juju9704. The second term of Taylor expansion